# How to disambiguate column names in yii MANY_MANY relation

Tags: activerecord, yii, disambiguation

I have a nice case of folder and item in the folder. All mysql is abbreviated for clarity.

```
CREATE TABLE folder
  folder_id INT,
  name VARCHAR(32),
  sort_weight INT

CREATE TABLE item
   item_id INT,
   name VARCHAR(32)
```

and of course the linking table

```
 CREATE TABLE item_folder
   folder_id INT,
   item_id INT,
   sort_weight INT
```

As you might have guessed one item can be in more than one folder (sort of like hard links in linux file system) and notice that folder has sort_weight too becuase it can be sorted inside another folder. Now I am using Yii and I have a nice relation in Item model like this:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'folderitems' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Folder', 'item_folder(item_id, folder_id)'),
    );
}
```

The problem is that when I try to make some nice AR request and I try to sort it I have a problem. My AR request:

```
$items = Item::model()->with(array(
  'folderitems' => array(
     'condition' => "folderitems.folder_id = $someid"
   ),
))->findAll(array('order'=> "folderitems.sort_weight"));
```

Now the problem is, that with syntax like this, instead of sorting by item_folder.sort_weight it sorts by folder.sort_weight.

If I change the name of the field to say item_folder.sort_weight2 and try:

```
[...] ))->findAll(array('order'=> 'sort_weight2'));
```

it works.

However if I keep both names the same and try

```
[...] ))->findAll(array('order'=> 'item_folder.sort_weight'));
```

it says `unknown column`.

So the question is - how to disambiguate it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
[...] ))->findAll(array('order'=> 't.sort_weight'));
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#disambiguating-column-names

"When a column name appears in two or more tables being joined together, it needs to be disambiguated. This is done by prefixing the column name with its table's alias name.

In relational AR query, the alias name for the primary table is fixed as t, while the alias name for a relational table is the same as the corresponding relation name by default."